# Парсинг контента (Python, BeautifulSoup, requests)

Tags: python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Вот код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://kaliningrad.bankiros.ru/currency/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

div_tags1 = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'currency-value'})
img_tags1 = [div.find('span') for div in div_tags1]

image_src1 = [img['data-curse-val'] for img in img_tags1]

valist = list(image_src1)

print(valist)
```

Я ещё учусь парсить и не понимаю, почему передаётся пустой список на выходе, ведь всё вроде сделал как всегда.

Как мне можно запарсить валюту с сайта https://kaliningrad.bankiros.ru/currency/ ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `HTTP` заголовок `User-Agent` к Вашему запросу:

```py
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',  # Example
}
html = requests.get('https://kaliningrad.bankiros.ru/currency/', headers=HEADERS).text
```